# Android: отслеживание изменения даты

Tags: java, android, listener

Ситуация следующая: есть TextView, текст отличается в зависимости от того, какая дата в системе. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы это изменение происходило динамически.

Пока что нашёл как сделать ежеминутную проверку даты, но это не совсем то. Можно ли сделать Listener, который слушает системную дату всё время, а не посылает запросы через какие-то интервалы? Допустим, открыл окно с TextView в 23:59, через минуту текст поменялся без перезапуска программы или рефреша.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование AsyncTask в данном случае плохая практика. Однозначно подобные задачи решаются через BroadcastReceiver. То есть, по наступлении определенного события, система рассылает "сообщения" приложениям. Если в приложении есть BroadcastReceiver, отвечающий за данное сообщение, произойдет необходимое действие.

Примерно так:

а) Добавляем в Android manifest (в application) следующее (у меня был свой пример с переключением режима "В полете", но там же можно посмотреть и другие варианты, например, android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED, что нам и нужно).

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.MyAirplaneReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

б) Создаем класс, который будет отвечать за данное действие, например:

```
public class MyAirplaneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("myLog", "Просто выводим лог!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое так работает, при смене даты код выполняется.

Comment: есть ещё один нюанс, который интересует. Broadcast Receiver, насколько я понимаю, работает, когда activity в стадии running. Например, если я из приложения ушёл в настройки, поменял там дату вручную, а потом открыл обратно, то Broadcast Receiver это событие не ловит.

Я сейчас сделал, чтобы код из onCreate исполнялся также в onResume и onStart. Вроде бы всё работает, но я хотел узнать, насколько это порочная практика? Так делают разработчики или лучше изучить Background Services?

Comment: Нет, он как раз работает всегда. Можно просмотреть мой пример для эксперимента. Логи будут выводиться всегда, независимо от того, работает приложение или нет. Описанное событие (смена даты пользователем в настройках) просто не перехватывается этим ресивером (данный бродкастресивер действует только тогда, когда дата меняется "ненасильственным" методом). И да, это совершенно нормальная практика, когда код таких проверок добавляется в методы жизненного цикла (я бы оставил эту проверку только в onResume). Позднее вы еще столкнетесь с permissions, там с этими проверками еще хуже :)

Comment: спасибо, познавательно :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать AsyncTask - в нем в с нужным интервалом считывать время и уже изменять TextView - динамический.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи можете воспользоваться виджетом **TextClock**, который отображает текущее время в системе и обновляется динамически: [подробнее.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html)

Однако, экземпляр класса **TextClock** не имеет методов возвращения значения времени.
Для этого лучше создать экземпляр класса `Date (java.util)` и воспользоваться методом `getTime():` [подробнее.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())